# Creating new pandas dataframe from certain columns of existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have read a csv file into a pandas dataframe and want to do some simple manipulations on the dataframe. I can not figure out how to create a new dataframe based on selected columns from my original dataframe. My attempt:

```py
names = ['A','B','C','D']
dataset = pandas.read_csv('file.csv', names=names)
new_dataset = dataset['A','D']
```

I would like to create a new dataframe with the columns A and D from the original dataframe.

Comment: Pass a list of the cols of interest to sub-select: `new_dataset = dataset[['A','D']]` note that if you're intending to operate on a copy then call `copy()`: `new_dataset = dataset[['A','D']].copy()`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is called `subset` - passed list of columns in `[]`:

```
dataset = pandas.read_csv('file.csv', names=names)

new_dataset = dataset[['A','D']]
```

what is same as:

```
new_dataset = dataset.loc[:, ['A','D']]
```

If need only filtered output add parameter `usecols` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
new_dataset = pandas.read_csv('file.csv', names=names, usecols=['A','D'])
```

EDIT:

If use only:

```
new_dataset = dataset[['A','D']]
```

and use some data manipulation, obviously get:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

If you modify values in `new_dataset` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`dataset`), and that Pandas does warning.

As pointed [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035929/creating-new-pandas-dataframe-from-certain-columns-of-existing-dataframe#comment77045763_45035929) add [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) for remove warning:

```
new_dataset = dataset[['A','D']].copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a list of column names to select columns. Otherwise, it will be interpreted as MultiIndex; `df['A','D']` would work if `df.columns` was MultiIndex.

The most obvious way is `df.loc[:, ['A', 'B']]` but there are other ways (note how all of them take lists):

```py
df1 = df.filter(items=['A', 'D'])

df1 = df.reindex(columns=['A', 'D'])

df1 = df.get(['A', 'D']).copy()
```

N.B. `items` is the first positional argument, so  `df.filter(['A', 'D'])` also works.

Note that `filter()` and `reindex()` return a copy as well, so you don't need to worry about getting `SettingWithCopyWarning` later.