# How do you iterate through groups in a pandas Dataframe, operate on each group, then assign values to the original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
    yearCount = df[['antibiotic', 'order_date', 'antiYearCount']]

    yearGroups = yearCount.groupby('order_date')

    for year in yearGroups:
        yearCount['antiYearCount'] =year.groupby('antibiotic'['antibiotic'].transform(pd.Series.value_counts)
```

In this case, `yearCount` is a dataframe containing `'order_date', 'antibiotic', 'antiYearCount'`. I have cleaned `'order_date'` to only contain the year of the order. I want to group `yearCount` by the years in `'order_date'`, count the number of times each `'antibiotic'` appears in each "year group" then assign that value to `yearCount`'s `'antiYearCount'` variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need add new column `order_date` to `groupby` and then is also possible use`size` instead `pd.Series.value_counts` for same output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'antibiotic':list('accbbb'),
                   'antiYearCount':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'order_date': pd.to_datetime(['2012-01-01']*3+['2012-01-02']*3)})

print (df)
   C  D  E  antiYearCount antibiotic order_date
0  7  1  5              4          a 2012-01-01
1  8  3  3              5          c 2012-01-01
2  9  5  6              4          c 2012-01-01
3  4  7  9              5          b 2012-01-02
4  2  1  2              5          b 2012-01-02
5  3  0  4              4          b 2012-01-02

#copy for remove warning
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/45035966/2901002
yearCount = df[['antibiotic', 'order_date', 'antiYearCount']].copy()
yearCount['antiYearCount'] = yearCount.groupby(['order_date','antibiotic'])['antibiotic'] \
                                      .transform('size')
print (yearCount)
  antibiotic order_date  antiYearCount
0          a 2012-01-01              1
1          c 2012-01-01              2
2          c 2012-01-01              2
3          b 2012-01-02              3
4          b 2012-01-02              3
5          b 2012-01-02              3
```

---

```
yearCount['antiYearCount'] = yearCount.groupby(['order_date','antibiotic'])['antibiotic'] \
                                      .transform(pd.Series.value_counts)
print (yearCount)
  antibiotic order_date  antiYearCount
0          a 2012-01-01              1
1          c 2012-01-01              2
2          c 2012-01-01              2
3          b 2012-01-02              3
4          b 2012-01-02              3
5          b 2012-01-02              3
```

Comment: jezrael has a great answer, I was able to fix it in the meantime. groupby returns a tuple, in this case year[0] is the year being iterated on and year[1] is the df where values of order_date are year[0]. By doing the same groupby function on year[1]

Comment: Hmmm, I think loop is not necessary, so your solution can be changed to my sol?

Comment: Right! It was running in under a second on 1.7M rows so I didnt consider. Thanks so much!