# Pandas groupby fillna on multiple new columns using .loc

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, fillna

Consider the following dataframe:

```
In [279]: edf = pd.DataFrame({
     ...:     'person': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
     ...:     'a': [1, 2, np.nan, 5, 10],
     ...:     'b': [1, np.nan, np.nan, 7, 15]
     ...: })

In [280]: edf
Out[280]: 
   person     a     b
0       1   1.0   1.0
1       1   2.0   NaN
2       1   NaN   NaN
3       2   5.0   7.0
4       2  10.0  15.0
```

I need to create two new columns named `c` and `d` which values are mapped from columns `a` and `b`. However, it seems that using `.loc` does not work in my case:

```
In [281]: edf.loc[:, ['c', 'd']] = edf.groupby('person')[['a', 'b']].fillna(method='ffill')

In [282]: edf
Out[282]: 
   person     a     b   c   d
0       1   1.0   1.0 NaN NaN
1       1   2.0   NaN NaN NaN
2       1   NaN   NaN NaN NaN
3       2   5.0   7.0 NaN NaN
4       2  10.0  15.0 NaN NaN
```

It works if I assign the values without `.loc`:

```
In [283]: edf[['c', 'd']] = edf.groupby('person')[['a', 'b']].fillna(method='ffill')

In [284]: edf
Out[284]: 
   person     a     b     c     d
0       1   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
1       1   2.0   NaN   2.0   1.0
2       1   NaN   NaN   2.0   1.0
3       2   5.0   7.0   5.0   7.0
4       2  10.0  15.0  10.0  15.0
```

However, I'm receiving this warning from Jupyter Lab if I use assignments shown in `In [283]`. I'm wondering which operation would be the most efficient and pythonic in this case? And what are the caveats, particularly in this case, between using and not using `.loc` in the assignment?

```
/xxx/xxx/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3069: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self[k1] = value[k2]
```

Of course we can do this explicitly, but I prefer to have it as a one-liner:

```
In [286]: edf2['c'] = edf.groupby('person')['a'].fillna(method='ffill')

In [287]: edf2.loc[:, 'd'] = edf.groupby('person')['b'].fillna(method='ffill')

In [288]: edf2
Out[288]: 
   person     a     b     c     d
0       1   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
1       1   2.0   NaN   2.0   1.0
2       1   NaN   NaN   2.0   1.0
3       2   5.0   7.0   5.0   7.0
4       2  10.0  15.0  10.0  15.0
```

The complete code as follow:

```
In [279]: edf = pd.DataFrame({
     ...:     'person': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
     ...:     'a': [1, 2, np.nan, 5, 10],
     ...:     'b': [1, np.nan, np.nan, 7, 15]
     ...: })

In [280]: edf
Out[280]: 
   person     a     b
0       1   1.0   1.0
1       1   2.0   NaN
2       1   NaN   NaN
3       2   5.0   7.0
4       2  10.0  15.0

In [281]: edf.loc[:, ['c', 'd']] = edf.groupby('person')[['a', 'b']].fillna(method='ffill')

In [282]: edf // Using .loc, it produces NaN instead of values in `a` and `b`
Out[282]: 
   person     a     b   c   d
0       1   1.0   1.0 NaN NaN
1       1   2.0   NaN NaN NaN
2       1   NaN   NaN NaN NaN
3       2   5.0   7.0 NaN NaN
4       2  10.0  15.0 NaN NaN

In [283]: edf[['c', 'd']] = edf.groupby('person')[['a', 'b']].fillna(method='ffill')  // This assignment works as I'm expecting

In [284]: edf
Out[284]: 
   person     a     b     c     d
0       1   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
1       1   2.0   NaN   2.0   1.0
2       1   NaN   NaN   2.0   1.0
3       2   5.0   7.0   5.0   7.0
4       2  10.0  15.0  10.0  15.0

In [285]: edf2 = pd.DataFrame({
     ...:     'person': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
     ...:     'a': [1, 2, np.nan, 5, 10],
     ...:     'b': [1, np.nan, np.nan, 7, 15]
     ...: })

In [286]: edf2['c'] = edf.groupby('person')['a'].fillna(method='ffill')

In [287]: edf2['d'] = edf.groupby('person')['b'].fillna(method='ffill')

In [288]: edf2   // Explicit assignments above work as I'm expecting
Out[288]: 
   person     a     b     c     d
0       1   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
1       1   2.0   NaN   2.0   1.0
2       1   NaN   NaN   2.0   1.0
3       2   5.0   7.0   5.0   7.0
4       2  10.0  15.0  10.0  15.0

In [289]: edf2.loc[:, 'c'] = edf.groupby('person')['a'].fillna(method='ffill')

In [290]: edf2  // This assignment works for assigning one column `c`
Out[290]: 
   person     a     b     c     d
0       1   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
1       1   2.0   NaN   2.0   1.0
2       1   NaN   NaN   2.0   1.0
3       2   5.0   7.0   5.0   7.0
4       2  10.0  15.0  10.0  15.0

In [291]: edf2['e'] = edf.groupby('person')['b'].fillna(method='ffill')

In [292]: edf2  // This assignment works as intended (without .loc) but it throws SettingCopyWarning
Out[292]: 
   person     a     b     c     d     e
0       1   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
1       1   2.0   NaN   2.0   1.0   1.0
2       1   NaN   NaN   2.0   1.0   1.0
3       2   5.0   7.0   5.0   7.0   7.0
4       2  10.0  15.0  10.0  15.0  15.0

In [293]: edf2.loc['f'] = edf.groupby('person')['b'].fillna(method='ffill')  // Single assignment with .loc works, but with SettingCopyWarning

In [294]: edf2
Out[294]: 
   person     a     b     c     d     e
0     1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
1     1.0   2.0   NaN   2.0   1.0   1.0
2     1.0   NaN   NaN   2.0   1.0   1.0
3     2.0   5.0   7.0   5.0   7.0   7.0
4     2.0  10.0  15.0  10.0  15.0  15.0
f     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: `SettingWithCopyWarning: ` is only in real data, right? In sample no error?

Comment: `edf` is created by some filtration?

Comment: `edf` is created for illustration purpose. Yes, I always use `.loc` to assign values, but in a multiple columns scenario, it doesn't seem to work as I am expecting (see `In [281]` where it assigns `NaN` values instead of the intended values)

Comment: for me `edf[['c', 'd']] = edf.groupby('person')[['a', 'b']].fillna(method='ffill')` working with no error.

Comment: So I think `SettingWithCopyWarning` cause another problem, it is unfortunately error, where is problem in some lines of code before error lines. So is necessaty use `copy` for filtration for avoid error.

Comment: Yes, mine also works without `.loc` but it throws warning `SettingWithCopyWarning`. I tried a simple assignments as follow: `edf2.loc[:, ['c', 'd']] = edf2.loc[:, ['a', 'b']]` and it assigns `NaN` to columns `c` and `d` instead of the values from `a` and `b`. However, without using `.loc` in this simple assignment, it assigns the values as intended. I'm wondering whether I should or should not use `.loc` in this case

Comment: hmm, I think `loc` is not solution for avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`, so if not possible find problem is possible post complete your code? I can find problem.

Comment: I says about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204404/settingwithcopywarning-after-using-copy/55204409#55204409) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035929/creating-new-pandas-dataframe-from-certain-columns-of-existing-dataframe/45035966#45035966)

Comment: Btw, maybe warning is because assign from one Dataframe to another `edf` to `edf2` e.g. here `edf2['e'] = edf.groupby('person')['b'].fillna(method='ffill')`