# Getting SettingWithCopyWarning with iloc or loc when some filtering is done on the dataframe wit regex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following statement to compute the mean of three quiz scores and create a new column based on the computed mean:

```
scores.loc[:, 'Average'] = scores[['Quiz1', 'Quiz2', 'Quiz3']].mean(axis=1).round(2)
```

However this leads to the following warning:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

After the dataframe is changed with the following set of operations, this warning shows up:

```
pattern = r'(?:^|\D)(\d{7})(?!\d)'
regex = re.compile(pattern)
scores = scores[scores['StudentId'].apply(lambda x: (regex.search(x) != None))]
scores
```

Any ideas why this filtering based on `regex` causes this error?

Comment: Problem is in code before `scores.loc[:, 'Average'] = scores[['Quiz1', 'Quiz2', 'Quiz3']].mean(axis=1).round(2)`, how is created `scores` ? there is some filtration? then need `.copy` like `scores = df[df.col == 1].copy()`

Comment: @jezrael all changes were directly applied to `scores` dataframe. `scores` were initially created from an excel file.

Comment: what is code between `cores.loc[:, 'Average'] = scores[['Quiz1', 'Quiz2', 'Quiz3']].mean(axis=1).round(2)` and `read_excel` ? Is possible add to question?

Comment: thank you, need `scores = scores[scores['StudentId'].apply(lambda x: (regex.search(x) != None))].copy()` for avoid warning

Comment: @jezrael I have identified the statements that led to this warning. Thanks for pointing me in this direction. But, I still cannot understand why they result in this warning?

Comment: @jezrael why? For other filtering I have done (e.g., `scores = 
scores[scores['Quiz1'] > 30]`), I never added `.copy()`. Why now?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035929/creating-new-pandas-dataframe-from-certain-columns-of-existing-dataframe/45035966#45035966)

Comment: If no modify `scores` later no warning. But if modify warning is raised.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244019/discussion-between-renakre-and-jezrael).

Comment: @jezrael But, scores =  scores[scores['Quiz1'] > 30]) this also modifies it, but will not cause the same error?

Comment: modify means created new column so also raise error `scores['new'] = 1` similar like in question `cores.loc[:, 'Average'] = scores[['Quiz1', 'Quiz2', 'Quiz3']].mean(axis=1).round(2)`

Comment: `scores =  scores[scores['Quiz1'] > 30]` is filtration, it is source of warning if modify later.